# Django Migration fails because of incompatibility in foreign key type

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have added secondary_client and secondary_pi fields in List table and when I run migrations I am getting this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3780, "Referencing column 'secondary_client_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'todo_list_secondary_client_id_cd997cc0_fk_todo_client_id' are incompatible.")

This is my models.py:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

class List(models.Model):
    ...
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='client', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pi = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='pi', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secondary_client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='secondary_client', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secondary_pi = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='secondary_pi', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

The migrations are working on my local machine However failing on the server.

Comment: This would indicate that the type of db field for id column of the CLient table is different to the type of the foreignkey field. Have you changed the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting, or upgraded to django 3.2 recently? (3.2 changed from Int type to BigAutofield.)

Comment: Yeah. I have upgraded django. How can I change back the bigautofield  to int type?

Answer (score 0):

If you've upgraded from django version  less than 3.2 to  greater than 3.2, they will have different defaults for the field type of the ID field

In settings.py you can set the following:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

This should set the default back to what it was prior to 3.2. You can also set it to BigAutoField, the new default, and makemigrations should migrate your models to the new default, unless other defaults are set at the application level, in apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
    name = 'my_app'
```

...or for specific models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

If you don't have any valuable data, you could also simply remove your DB and migration files and re-migrate from scratch to use the new default.

Comment: It does not seem to be the case here but I had the same error message when I changed a ForeignKey relation from `Null=True` to `False`.

Using `./manage test` helped to debug the problem as this is running _all_ migrations, also the unapplied ones so it is easier to compare the error in different database states.